# How to use multiple conditions in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
elif(mud == 1 and game_select == 'Mud + Fire' or game_select == 'Fire + Mud'):
        do something
```

When game_select == 'Mud + Fire' it doesn't run if mud != 1, but it runs no matter what when game_select == 'Fire + Mud'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you need to wrap the and statement in the correct way.

```
elif(mud == 1 and (game_select == 'Mud + Fire' or game_select == 'Fire + Mud')):
      do something
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python evaluates `or` before it evaluates `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - this means it's reading your statement as "if mud is 1 and the string matches mud and fire, true. Or, if the string matches fire and mud, true."

You can get around this by properly splitting your statements up with parenthesis:

```py
elif(mud == 1 and (game_select == 'Mud + Fire' or game_select == 'Fire + Mud')):
        do something
```

This reads as "if mud is one, and the string matches fire and mud or mud and fire, true."